# Sequelize is allowing user to type "null" even with allowNull: false

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a model for an Itinerary

```
var Itinerary = sequelize.define('Itinerary', {
  title: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      notEmpty: true
    }
  }
})
```

This works for preventing empty inputs but if I type in "null" it still adds to my database. Reading the docs, it looks like it should prevent this from happening? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: are you literally setting title ="null" (i.e. a string with the value null)?

Comment: yes. Or am I understanding the docs incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize (and the db) is interpreting "null" as valid string.

```
itinerary.title ='null';
```

is different than:

```
itinerary.title = null;
```

you can add an additional validate method to your model to look for this string null if you'd like.

```
var Itinerary = sequelize.define('Itinerary', {
  title: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    nullorEmpty: function() {
      if (!this.title || (this.title === 'null') {
        throw new Error('title must be set')
      }
    }
  }
})
```